# CSOM: Is there a size limit for data being transmitted from SharePoint to me?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

Is there a limit on the amount of data that is being transmitted to the client? I'm not talking about the list view thresholds etc. This is about the actual bytes being transmitted from SharePoint to me.

I'm asking because I'm having Fiddler open while requesting data from SharePoint via CSOM and it is quite some amount that is being transferred. My current maximum is ~14 MB per call.

Screenshot from Fiddler:

[image]

Is there a limit? Can I request 50 MB? 100 MB? If there is a limit: is this configurable? Bonus: are there differences between SharePoint on-prem and Online?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, for SharePoint Server, the limit is like this:

> SharePoint has a 2 MB limit for an operations request, and a 50 MB
>   limit for the size of a submitted binary object. The request size is
>   limited to protect the server from excessively long queues of
>   operations and from processing delays for large binary objects.

For SharePoint Online, it is more dynamic.

> We continually monitor resource usage on SharePoint Online.
>   Depending on usage, we fine-tune thresholds so users can consume the
>   maximum number of resources without degrading the reliability and
>   performance of SharePoint Online. That's why it's so important for
>   your CSOM or REST code to honor the retry-after header value; this
>   lets your code run as fast as possible on any given day, and it lets
>   your code back off "just enough" if it hits throttling limits. The
>   code samples later in this article show you how to use the retry-after
>   header.

You would be better to check this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online).